# Are OBD-II devices capable of controlling acceleration and top speed of a car?

Tags: obd-ii, acceleration, obd, cruise-control, vehicle-speed-sensor

I have been searching for a while for some specific type of OBD-II devices that can, besides performing the usual diagnostics, also do the following:

- GPS track the car online
- Has the ability to set the cars acceleration speed
- Can limit the cars top speed

I haven't come across any that offer anything other than the GPS tracking. Am I safe in assuming that there aren't any such devices available to consumers? I was under the impression that car rental services used something similar?

Thank you.

Comment: No, you would need specialized software that can interface with the computer on the car, and does not exist for all Manufacturer and years.

Comment: You should search on here and then read all the similar questions and answers.